# debug & change ttf font outlines point

Tags: truetype

atfer i get out the glypg outlines points with Freetype2 liabry .... 
am using ttf font
if i want to debug the outline points ..so i need to change them and see the result ,

is there way to change them too? and if it possble can i save the new point (to the orgenal file.ttf) if not how can i see it.. (maybe draw the new points on some serface...)

please help , thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can also use TTX (fonttools, http://sourceforge.net/projects/fonttools/) for converting TrueType font to XML. Then you can editing it manually. When done, you recompile it whith TTX to have a binary font.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using font editors such as fontforge? see http://fontforge.sourceforge.net/

I believe you can visually modify the glyphs outline and save the resulting font.

I don't know of any quick way to visually check the glyph outlines points that FreeType2 generates but you can write your own "glyph viewer" using a GUI framework (eg, gtk+cario, wx). You will need to convert the point/commands sets into the correct MOVE_TO, LINE_TO, CURVE_TO, etc. This way you easily see the effect of your modified point.